# Angular: lazy loading module only for dev (environment.production === false)

Tags: angular

I have a lazy loaded module only for development purpose and i want don't deploy it into the production build.

With a guard i have denied the activation and the loading:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dev',
    loadChildren: './features/dev/dev.module#DevModule',
    canActivate: [DevelopmentGuard],
    canLoad: [DevelopmentGuard]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

the guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DevelopmentGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor() {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.can();
  }

  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.can();
  }

  canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): boolean {
    return this.can();
  }

  private can(): boolean {
    return (environment.production === false);
  }
}
```

it works, my dev module works only in dev, but the scripts of the dev module are in the build.

There is a way for totally remove the script from the build of the prod version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

option 1

```
let routes: Routes = []; // provide default rotes

if(!environment.production){
   routes = [...routes, [  {
    path: 'dev',
    loadChildren: './features/dev/dev.module#DevModule',
    canActivate: [DevelopmentGuard],
    canLoad: [DevelopmentGuard]
  },
]]
}
```

Options 2.

```
export let devRoutes: Routes = [];

if(!environment.production){
   devRoutes = [  {
    path: 'dev',
    loadChildren: './features/dev/dev.module#DevModule',
    canActivate: [DevelopmentGuard],
    canLoad: [DevelopmentGuard]
  }
 ]
}

RouterModule.forRoot([...routes, ...devRoutes])
```

With option 2 you can make it even better if you move devRoutes to environment config

Comment: @Drenai i also wasn't sure this is why i've tested before posting this answer. Have tried and it doesn't work?

Comment: thanks, seem works. moving dev route into environment config cause a Circular dependency developement.guard.ts -> src\environments\environment.ts -> developement.guard

Comment: @ar099968 why do you need guards there? as i understand its just for dev purposes

Comment: @Drenai I think this is correct behaviour since its ahead of time means it needs to load everything into memory and find dependencies.